# I want to make a new grouped dataframe that has only the dates with holidays in them using .weekday()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset, data-science

So i have a dataframe:

```
dateRep day month   year    cases   deaths  country_name    Land.area..sq..km.
0   2021-09-21  21  9   2021    1162    7   Austria 82520.0
1   2021-09-20  20  9   2021    1708    7   Austria 82520.0
2   2021-09-19  19  9   2021    2072    5   Austria 82520.0
3   2021-09-18  18  9   2021    2235    9   Austria 82520.0
4   2021-09-17  17  9   2021    2283    8   Austria 82520.0
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
6145    2021-03-05  5   3   2021    4069    15  Sweden  407310.0
6146    2021-03-04  4   3   2021    4882    19  Sweden  407310.0
6147    2021-03-03  3   3   2021    4873    18  Sweden  407310.0
6148    2021-03-02  2   3   2021    6191    23  Sweden  407310.0
6149    2021-03-01  1   3   2021    668975  13086   Sweden  407310.0
6150 rows × 8 columns
```

And my target is to make a new dataframe which has only rows that follow specific condition in 'dateRep' column

The condition is being a holiday (Sunday or Saturday) using .weekday() function

But the problem is when i tried doing

```
df.loc[(df['dateRep'].weekday() == 5) or (df['dateRep'].weekday == 6)]
```

I had an error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'weekday'`

What do i do? How do i sort out these rows and what is an easier way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the `dateRep` to datetime Series and use `.dt.` accessor:

```py
df["dateRep"] = pd.to_datetime(df["dateRep"])
print(df.loc[(df["dateRep"].dt.weekday == 5) | (df["dateRep"].dt.weekday == 6)])
```

Prints:

```
     dateRep  day  month  year  cases  deaths country_name  Land.area..sq..km.
2 2021-09-19   19      9  2021   2072       5      Austria             82520.0
3 2021-09-18   18      9  2021   2235       9      Austria             82520.0
```

---

OR: Use `.isin()` for shorter code:

```py
df.loc[df["dateRep"].dt.weekday.isin([5, 6])]
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej! You're saving me once again

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
df.loc[(df['dateRep'].dt.weekday == 5)|(df['dateRep'].dt.weekday == 6)]
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.weekday.html#pandas.Series.dt.weekday

Comment: No worries! Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Have you converted Data frame to a datetime type.If not do this
df['dateRep'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dateRep'])

Comment: Don't forget to format your code with indentation (four spaces, one empty lines above and below) to make it stand out